# ASP.NET Menu click zone

Tags: asp.net, menu

I am experimenting with the ASP.NET menu control and have it mostly the way I want, with one exception.  When I click on the *text* of a menu item, I am correctly redirected to the page that the menu item refers to.  But the rest of the empty space in the menu item does not respond to clicks.  This is fine for items where most of the item is full of text, but some of them have very short labels.  Is there any way to make the entire menu item respond to clicks?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a css class with this style **display: block**.

```
<StaticMenuItemStyle  CssClass="MenuFullClick" ...
<DynamicMenuItemStyle CssClass="MenuFullClick" ...

    <style type="text/css">
    /* Makes the highlight clickable instead of just the link */
    .MenuFullClick
    {
        width: 125px;
        display: block;
    }
```